# Why date format gets changed when I insert a date value into another cell in excel by using the '=' sign?

Tags: excel

Imagine a cell A1 has date 22-06-2022
In cell B1 I am entering this
=""""&A1&""""
I get the result as "44735" not "22-06-2022"

Answer (score 0):

It is because the B1 cell doesn't have a 'Date' format, only the A1 cell has it. B1 cell only has the number value of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

See [Date systems in Excel (1900 system)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-systems-in-excel-e7fe7167-48a9-4b96-bb53-5612a800b487).

> When you enter a date, it is converted into a serial number that represents the number of days elapsed since January 1, 1900. For example, if you enter July 5, 2011, Excel converts the date to the serial number 40729.

When you *see* the number `44735` as `22-06-2022` in `A1`, this means that the cell is formatted as `DD-MM-YYYY` (you can check this by selecting the cell and clicking `Ctrl + 1`).

So, instead of `=A1` (returning: 44735 as an integer), you could use `=TEXT(A1,"DD-MM-YY")` to produce the same string from the value in a different cell.